# How can I filter my result set by a field on the Many side of a @OneToMany relation on Ebean?

Tags: java, orm, playframework, ebean

I have my models setup like the following:

```
@Entity
public class A extends Model {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany
  List<B> bees;
}

@Entity
public class B extends Model {

  @Column{name = "STING"}
  private String sting;

  @ManyToOne
  @Column{name = "A_ID"}
  A aces;
}
```

How can I get the A which have B with reference to it with sting = 'READY'?

In sql it would be something like SELECT A.* FROM A, B WHERE A.ID = B.A_ID AND B.STING = 'READY'.

I'm using Ebean within Play Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use .eq("bees.sting", "READY") and the appropriate join will be automatically added for you.  So:

```
List<A> list = A.find.where().eq("bees.sting", "READY").findList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the .where on a OneToMany without a fetch,if Rob's answer doesn't work, try this.

```
List<A> list = A.find.fetch("bees").where().eq("t1.sting", "READY").findList();
```

The t1 got me for a while, but the generated SQL seemed to make the join table clear.  I'm using PostgreSQL.